# JDBC connection pool never shrinks

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I run 3 processes at the same time , all of them are using the same DB (RDS postgres)
all of them are java application that uses JDBC for connecting to the DB

I am using `PGPoolingDataSource` in every process as a connection pool for the DB

every request is handled by the book - ended with

```
finally{
  connection.close();
}
```

main problems:
1.

1. I ran out of connections really fast because I do a massive work
   with the DB at the beginning (which is ok) but the pool never
   shrinks.
2. I get some exceptions in the code because there are not enough connections and I wish I could expand the timeout when a requesting
   a connection.

My insights:

1. the `PGPoolinDataSource` never shrinks by definition!  I couldn't find any documentation about it, but I assume this is the case. So I tried the apache DBCP pool and again I am having the same problem .
2. I think there must be timeout when waiting for a connection - I would guess that this timeout can be configured, but I couldn't find this configuration on both pools .

My Questions:

1. why does the pool never shrinks?!
2. how to determine how many connections to allocate for each pool\process (here every process has one pool)
3. what happens if I don't close the pool (not the connections) and the app is dead does the connections on the pool are still alive? this happens a lot when I update the application I stop and start it so I never close the pool.
4. what would be a good JDBC connection pool that works best with postgres and that has  an option to set the timeout for the getConnection ?

Thanks